# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am developing an android app that I have tested successfully on Android version 4.2.2 and 4.3 but since wide compatibility is also required for this app I also attempted to test it using Gingerbread 2.3.6 but it crashed. The libraries used are android-support-v4 and v7 app tomcat and also google-play-services.

Here is the logcat log displayed:

```
11-04 10:20:54.736: W/dalvikvm(17136): Link of class 'Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/MainActivity;' failed
11-04 10:20:54.736: E/dalvikvm(17136): Could not find class 'dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.MainActivity', referenced from method dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.SplashScreen$1.run
11-04 10:20:54.736: W/dalvikvm(17136): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1319 (Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/MainActivity;) in Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/SplashScreen$1;
11-04 10:20:54.736: D/dalvikvm(17136): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0004
11-04 10:20:54.736: D/dalvikvm(17136): VFY: dead code 0x0006-0013 in Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/SplashScreen$1;.run ()V
11-04 10:20:56.740: W/dalvikvm(17136): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.MainActivity
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:26)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-04 10:20:56.748: E/AndroidRuntime(17136):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 10:26:01.459: I/Process(17136): Sending signal. PID: 17136 SIG: 9
11-04 10:27:39.236: W/dalvikvm(17338): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.MainActivity
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:26)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-04 10:27:39.248: E/AndroidRuntime(17338):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 10:32:42.724: I/Process(17338): Sending signal. PID: 17338 SIG: 9
11-04 10:36:34.705: D/dalvikvm(17486): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 56K, 48% free 2838K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 22ms
11-04 10:36:34.771: I/dalvikvm(17486): Failed resolving Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/MainActivity; interface 12 'Landroid/app/ActionBar$TabListener;'
11-04 10:36:34.771: W/dalvikvm(17486): Link of class 'Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/MainActivity;' failed
11-04 10:36:34.771: E/dalvikvm(17486): Could not find class 'dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.MainActivity', referenced from method dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.SplashScreen$1.run
11-04 10:36:34.771: W/dalvikvm(17486): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1319 (Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/MainActivity;) in Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/SplashScreen$1;
11-04 10:36:34.771: D/dalvikvm(17486): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0004
11-04 10:36:34.771: D/dalvikvm(17486): VFY: dead code 0x0006-0013 in Ldk/thesweetapps/vejviseraktivgravid/SplashScreen$1;.run ()V
11-04 10:36:36.775: W/dalvikvm(17486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.MainActivity
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:26)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-04 10:36:36.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17486):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import java.util.Calendar;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.Preferences.SettingsActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    public static final String tag = "thesweetapps";
    ViewPager viewPager;
    String timeForReminderPreference;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        timeForReminderPreference = sharedPreferences.getString("time_for_reminder", "15:00");
        //It returns the pages/tabs
        SetTabBar();
        SetNotifications();
    }


    private void SetNotifications() {

        Log.e(tag, "inside setNotification");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , Notification.class);  
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getHour(timeForReminderPreference));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getMinute(timeForReminderPreference));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String changedForReminderPreference = sharedPreferences
                .getString("time_for_reminder", "15:00");
        if(timeForReminderPreference != changedForReminderPreference ){
             timeForReminderPreference = changedForReminderPreference;
             SetNotifications();
        }
    }

    private void SetTabBar() {
        pagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        //setting the actionbar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        Log.d(tag, "setting actionbar");
        //actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //setting the viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        Log.d(tag, "setting viewPager");

        //adding pages to actionbar
        for(int i = 0; i<pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this).setIcon(pagerAdapter.getIcon(i)));
        }
        Log.d(tag, "added tabs");
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.e(tag, "inside opOptionsItemSelected: "+item.getItemId());
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                open();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void open() {
        Log.e(tag, "inside open settings");
        //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());    
    }

    @Override

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
}

public static int getHour(String time) {
    String[] pieces = time.split(":");

    return (Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]));
}

public static int getMinute(String time) {
    String[] pieces = time.split(":");
    return (Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]));
}
```

}

SplashScreen.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

AndroidManifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!--map xml starts here-->
     <permission
        android:name="dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

     <!--  Android API uses OpenGL ES version 2 to render the map. 
     If OpenGL ES version 2 is not installed, your map will not appear -->
     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" 
        android:required="true" />

      <uses-permission android:name="dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
      <!-- Used by the API to download map tiles from Google Maps servers. -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <!-- External storage for caching. -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
      <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services. -->
      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
      <!-- Allows the API to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location. -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
      <!-- Allows the API to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) to determine the device's location to within a very small area.  -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

      <!-- map xml ends here -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >

         <!-- Specific key for every android app you need to get from 
         https://code.google.com/apis/console left at the API acess bar-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
             android:value="AIzaSyDrqs5I0mXD7lx_excAQJQT-a7DNbhAu0Q" />

        <activity
            android:name="dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

        <activity android:label="Personlig indstilling"
            android:name="dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.Preferences.SettingsActivity"></activity>
        <receiver android:name="dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.Notification"></receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: I guess `dk.thesweetapps.vejviseraktivgravid.MainActivity` is your MainActivity shown here. Make sure the package is correct. This error sometimes happen when switching SDKs or versions, try to clean the project and make sure you're not getting any errors when building. Restarting Eclipse also helps.

Comment: Yes it is indeed, I did try that it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Hi @AlexandruPatriche did you fix this problem, i have the same issue with devices using OS 2.3 ... :(